# Juntar vários arquivos de uma pasta no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando juntar vários arquivos xlsx no R.
Para isso, primeiro abro as library a seguir e utilizo a programação:

```
library(readxl)
library(plyr)
larquivos<-list.files("C:\\Users\\tomas.veiga\\Documents\\Financeiro\\dados",full.names=TRUE)
arquivos <- lapply(larquivos, function(x) read_excel(path = x, sheet = 1))
```

Como os arquivos possuem diferença no número de linhas, tento fazer o seguinte:

```
extracontab<-data.frame(rbind.fill(arquivos[c(1:12)]))
```

Mas volta um erro:

```
Error in vector(type, length) :   vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'NULL'.
```

Tento também fazer assim:

```
extracontab<-data.frame(rbind.fill(arquivos[c(1:12)]))
```

Mas nada funciona. O que devo fazer?
Obrigado.

Comment: Tem como conseguir um exemplo reprodutível dos dados como o mesmo problema? Experimentei aqui com tabelas quaisquer e a linha `extracontab<-data.frame(rbind.fill(arquivos[c(1:12)]))` funciona normalmente (apesar do `[c(1:12]` ser redundante). Isso indica que possivelmente os arquivos não foram lidos corretamente, ou então o problema tem a ver com a estrutura das tabelas.

Comment: Ocorreu o mesmo comigo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consegui reproduzir o seu erro usando uma planilha com nome de coluna vazio. Provavelmente é esse o seu problema.

Para resolver eu faria assim:

```
arquivos <- lapply(larquivos, function(x) {
  df <- read_excel(path = x, sheet = 1)
  names(df)[names(df) == ""] <- "x__"
  return(df)
})
```

E depois chamaria o `rbind.fill` da mesma forma que você está fazendo. As linhas que adicionei apenas modificam o nome das colunas em branco para "x__". Você pode preferir outra ação como excluí-las, colocar outro nome, etc. Para isso, basta modificar a função chamada pelo `lapply`.

Comment: Daniel, fiz de outro jeito como expliquei na resposta embaixo. Como a sua forma é muito mais elegante do que retirar uma coluna, queria entender melhor o que foi feito. O que significa essa função return?

Comment: Ela diz qual o valor que a função `retorna` depois de ter sido executada. O trecho acima continuaria sendo igual caso se trocasse `return(df)` por `df`. A diferença é que `return` permite que a função possa retornar em outros pontos, e não necessariamente na última linha.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz dessa maneira:

```
larquivos<-list.files("C:/Users/tomas.veiga/Documents/Financeiro/dados",full.names=TRUE)
arquivos <- sapply(larquivos, read_excel,simplify = F)
dados <- rbindlist(arquivos, idcol = "id")
```

E depois retirei as colunas que queria.